# Would it be possible to use Hadoop for automatic process balancing without using HDFS

Tags: java, hibernate, hadoop

I know that it is possible to distribute jobs over a hadoop cluster. Also do i know that it is possible to read and write semi-directly to SQL Databases from within an hadoop system.

My question is more directed as, is it done, in the real world, that data is read and write from files and a relational database from within hadoop jobs and then, after processing written back to the relational database. So using hadoop directly as process balancer, with something like hibernate and without the use of HDFS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Because you wont have access to the records in setup and clean up tasks of mapper and reducer. 
Out of hdfs, the only way to execute the jobs is to input/output with local file system.